# Deleting and freeing occupied space

Tags: macos, mac, usb, hdd

Why when deleting from a USB or an external HDD on mac the occupied space wont be free untill deleted from trash?

Is there a direct way to delete from the drive and freeing the occupied space instantly?

Answer (score 2):

One way to bypass the trash without any additional tools is to open a Terminal window, type `rm -rf` (note the last space) and the drag/drop the files/folders to be deleted and press enter. This will instantly and recursively delete the files/folders, so be careful with it!

Comment: Thank you for the answer upvote for that.. but I'm aware of the terminal solution, hope to find a quick way without the terminal's use